# Drag and drop do not send the data as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Note:I'm new to javascript.
I have the following code which allows the user to preview an image before uploading it.
The input element works fine and the selected image is displayed as expected.
However, the drag and drop throws an error that,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

I think I am taking the dropped file object in a wrong way any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function renderImage(file)
    {
    var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(event) {
    the_url = event.target.result
       $('#preview').html("<img width='150px' height = '100px'src='" + the_url + "' />")
       }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    //This is for the input and works fine.
    $('#file').change( function (){
       renderImage(this.files[0])
  });
    //The drag is the one with problem.
    //it produces the following error
    /*
    *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
    */
    $("#drop").on('dragenter', function (e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).css('background', '#BBD5B8');
 });

 $("#drop").on('dragover', function (e){
 e.preventDefault();
 });

 $("#drop").on('drop', function (e){
 $(this).css('background', '#D8F9D3');
  e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
      var dt = e.target.files || (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files);
  var files = dt.files;
  renderImage(files);
 
 });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
#drop
{
 width:300px;
 height:100px;
 border:dotted 1px;
 border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "upload">
  <div id = "drop">
    </div>
  <input type ="file" id = "file">
  <div id = "preview">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is, where I corrected also the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined" (only for FF it's necessary to double the input field):

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function renderImage(file)
    {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        the_url = event.target.result
        $('#preview').html("<img width='150px' height = '100px'src='" + the_url + "' />")
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    //This is for the input and works fine.
    $('input[type^="file"]').change( function (){
      renderImage(this.files[0])
    });
    //The drag is the one with problem.
    //it produces the following error
    /*
                 *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
                 */
    $("#drop").on('dragenter', function (e){
      event.target.style.background = '#BBD5B8';
    });
    $("#drop").on('dragover', function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#drop").on('drop', function (e){
      event.target.style.background = '#D8F9D3';
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      var dt = (e.originalEvent.target.files && e.originalEvent.target.files.length > 0) || (e.originalEvent.dataTransfer && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
      var files = dt[0];
      renderImage(files);

    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#drop
{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  border:dotted 1px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
#drop input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  font-size: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#drop label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div id="upload">
    <div id="drop">
        <label id="fileLbl">Drop a file here</label>
        <input type ="file" id = "file1">
    </div>
    <input type ="file" id = "file2">
    <div id = "preview">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with your HTML. Try moving your input inside of your `#drop` div

```
<div id = "upload">
  <div id = "drop">
   <input type ="file" id = "file">
  </div>
  <div id = "preview">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to have two ways to upload the image (a)using the input and (b)the drop area.That's the reasons I placed them differently.

Comment: You may be better off using jQuery File Upload plugin. It already solves these issues. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: A pure Javascript solution is offered by DevBridge here: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/drag-and-drop-uploader/